# How to write case in update query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to use case in update query but it gives me error as

> Could not find stored procedure 'update dbo.ARInvoiceItems set Hideshowflag = 'case when Hideshowflag is null then Hideshowflag='N' e'.

In sql server 2005.following is my query which i used.

```
update dbo.ARInvoiceItems 
    set Hideshowflag =(
        case 
            when Hideshowflag is null then Hideshowflag='N'
            when Hideshowflag='N' then 'Y'
            when Hideshowflag='Y' then 'N' end`
where SOId=@SOID
```

Comment: If this is your actual code, you have a syntax error - you have not closed the bracket starting at `set Hideshowflag =(`.

Comment: "Could not find stored procedure" probably means there's something wrong with code which is supposed to *execute* this query. Showing that code might help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. You can also use `Or` within the logical statement of `CASE` as `Hideshowflag is null or Hideshowflag='Y'`

```
Update dbo.ARInvoiceItems 
    Set Hideshowflag =
        Case 
            When Hideshowflag is null or Hideshowflag='Y' Then  'N'
            When Hideshowflag='N' Then 'Y'
        End
Where SOId = @SOID
```

*OR* it can be done with a `Simple Case` for the same logic using `Isnull` or `Coalesce` as;

```
Update dbo.ARInvoiceItems 
    Set Hideshowflag =
        Case Isnull(Hideshowflag,'Y')
            When 'Y' Then  'N'
            When 'N' Then  'Y'
        End
Where SOId = @SOID
```

> Could not find stored procedure 'update dbo.ARInvoiceItems set
>   Hideshowflag = 'case when Hideshowflag is null then Hideshowflag='N'
>   e'.

I think you are trying to run above update query as a stored procedure. What you need is, [create a stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with above query (if you haven't done it) then execute the stored procedure using it's name as;

```
EXEC 'Your_procedure_name_should_go_here'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in the code you posted

```
UPDATE dbo.ARInvoiceItems
SET    Hideshowflag =  CASE
                          WHEN Hideshowflag IS NULL THEN  'N'
                          WHEN Hideshowflag = 'N' THEN 'Y'
                          WHEN Hideshowflag = 'Y' THEN 'N'
                        END 
WHERE  SOId = @SOID
```

But the error message you say you are getting

> Could not find stored procedure 'update dbo.ARInvoiceItems set Hideshowflag = ...

usually happens if you do `EXEC @Foo` instead of `EXEC (@Foo)`

Is this statement in a string variable that you are `EXEC`-ing?

Answer (score -1):

This is what you want

```
 DECLARE @TEMP table
    (
        jobid int IDENTITY (1,1),
        statusCode int
    )

    INSERT INTO @TEMP
    SELECT 15 UNION 
    SELECT 114 UNION 
    SELECT 14 UNION 
    SELECT 152 UNION 
    SELECT 41 

    SELECT * FROM @TEMP

    DECLARE @jobid int  = 3, @statusCode int = 40

    UPDATE @TEMP
    SET statusCode = (CASE WHEN @statusCode = 40 THEN 15 ELSE 14 END)
    WHERE jobid = @jobid

    SELECT * FROM @TEMP
```